# Showing only certain forms of a database

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, database

If possible, I would prefer to only use HTML or Ruby. I'm trying to make an note feature for trades on my fantasy football application, and I would like to be able to organize it by team involved. For example, when entering a new note, I would specify what team I would be trading with. After finishing creating the note in my database, I would be able to go to a page, choose the team that I entered the note with, and see all the notes involving that team. Basically, I am wondering how to show certain information in a database dependent on one of the form answers. Here is my Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.

  def index_note
    @note = Note.all
  end

  def create_note
    n = Note.new
    n.team = params['team']
    n.title = params['title']
    n.pin = params['pin']
    n.pout = params['pout']
    n.pw = params['pw']
    n.otrade = params['otrade']
    n.save
    redirect_to "/index_notes"
  end

  def edit_note
    @note = Note.find_by_id(params['id'])
  end

  def update_note
    n = Note.find_by_id(params['id'])
    n.team = params['team']
    n.title = params['title']
    n.pin = params['pin']
    n.pout = params['pout']
    n.pw = params['pw']
    n.otrade = params['otrade']
    n.save
    redirect_to "/index_notes"
   end

  def destroy_note
    n = Note.find_by_id(params['id'])
    n.destroy
    redirect_to '/index_note'
  end

end
```

Here is my new_note page

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-md-12">
      <br  />
      <div style="background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" class="jumbotron"> 
        <h2 class="text-center">Add a Trade Note</h2>
        <br  />
        <br  />
        <h4 class="text-center">
          <form action="/create_note">
            <p>
              <input type="text" name="team" placeholder="Team Involved">
            </p>
            <br  />
            <p>
              <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
            </p>
            <br  />
            <p>
              <input type="text" name="pin" placeholder="Incoming Players">
            </p>
            <br  />
            <p>
              <input type="text" name="pout" placeholder="Outgoing Players">
            </p>
            <br  />
            <p>
              <input type="text" name="pw" placeholder="Position Wanted">
            </p>
             <br  />
             <p>
               <input type="text" name="otrade" placeholder="Other Trades Needed">    
            </p>
            <br  />
            <p>
              <input type="submit">
            </p>
          </form>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my index_note page

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div style="background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class = "text-center"> Trade Ideas</h1>
          <br  />
          <br  />
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <th class= "pwsth">Title</th>
            <th class= 'pwsth'>Team</th>
            <th class= "pwsth">Position Wanted</th>
            <th class = 'pwsth'>View</th>
            <th class = 'pwsth'>Update</th>
            <th class = 'pwsth'>Destroy</th>
          </tr>
         <% @note.each do |note| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%=note.title%></td>
              <td><%=note.team%></td>
              <td><%=note.pw%></td>
              <td><a href="/note/<%= note.id %>">View</a></td>
              <td><a href="/edit_note/<%= note.id %>">Update</a>
              <td><a href="/destroy_note/<%= note.id %>">Destroy</a>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify model relations in rails so something like:

```
class Team < ApplicationController

has_many :notes

end

class Note < ApplicationController

belongs_to :team

end
```

Then in the database you've got team_id field for note record which ties it into a relation with a team.

Then you can query for all the team notes by something like

```
Team.first.notes
```

This is quite an open ended topic so just have a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html